# change Zend_Oauth_Consumer adapter?

Tags: twitter, zend-framework, oauth, twitter-oauth

Is it possible to change the `adapter` of `Zend_Oauth_Consumer`?

On the customer his server they rely on `Zend_Oauth_Consumer` to login a user through facebook or twitter. Sadly enough the normal adapter (`Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket`) throws an error.

So, can that be changed?

Comment: what is the error by Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket

Comment: `Unable to Connect to ssl://api.twitter.com:443. Error #0 : `

So in short.. No error